Equivalent of "aws eks update-kubeconfig" from AWS Java SDK
Is there a way to perform the equivalent of aws eks update-kubeconfig from the Java AWS SDK v2?
If there is no direct equivalent, I'm wondering if there is a way to describe the cluster with the AWS SDK and then use information from that response to somehow create the kube config.
The describe cluster response should have the certificate-authority-data and server location.
The last part would be setting up the user and authentication. Ideally I'd like to be able to fill in a token, so then is there a way to call eks get-token from the AWS SDK?
